# How can NAs be replaced by percentage changes?

Tags: r, replace

My R data is similar to that in the "Start" column. I would like to replace the NAs, which vary in number in the dataframe. I can replace NAs by interpolation, as indicated in the second column; however, I would like to replace the NAs by equal percentage changes, as indicated in column 3, which, in this case, increases by 29.155% in each period. Note, though, that my column has many NAs of various lengths and various starting and ending numbers. I would like a method to apply to all of these situations.

| Start | Inter. | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 10.000 |
| NA | 20 | 12.916 |
| NA | 30 | 16.681 |
| NA | 40 | 21.544 |
| NA | 50 | 27.826 |
| NA | 60 | 35.938 |
| NA | 70 | 46.416 |
| NA | 80 | 59.949 |
| NA | 90 | 77.427 |
| 100 | 100 | 100.000 |

Comment: What language is this in? You should tag the question accordingly

Comment: Where did you get 29.155 from? Can you show full expected output?

Comment: 29.155, derived by trial and error (in excel), is the annual percent which, starting from 10, the starting point, creates 100, the end point. I am rounding to the third decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumprod()`,

```
first <- 10
last <- 100
rows <- 10
ratio <- (last/first)^(1/(rows-1))    

round(c(first,cumprod(rep((ratio),rows-1)) * rep(first,rows-1)),3)
```

gives,

```
# [1]  10.000  12.915  16.681  21.544  27.826  35.938  46.416  59.949  77.427 100.000
```

Comment: Thanks, but my NAs vary in number, and the starting and ending points also vary. Thus, 29.155 only applies to this specific case. Is there a method, like the interpolation method, for all cases?

Comment: 29.155 (ratio) is not defined in my answer. It is calculated with respect to start, end and number of the rows at this step : `ratio <- (last/first)^(1/(rows-1)) ` . So you can generalize it for any input.

Comment: But, with a long column of many NAs of various lengths, is there a way to identify the "first" and "last" in a column? As is done with the replace NAs with interpolation procedure?